# Existance of unique $n$-sphere

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, analytic-geometry

We know a sphere, in $\mathbb{R}^3$-space, is uniquely determined by four points that are not coplanar. Similarly, a hypersphere, in $\mathbb{R}^n$-space, is uniquely determined by $n+1$ points that are not cohyperplanar.

I was just wandering if there exists such a result for getting a unique hyper-ellipsoid? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Any smooth quadric in the complex projective plane is determined by five points (generic enough); you could try to generalise this to higher dimension, it should be useful. Note that a quadric hypersurface in n-dimensional complex projective space is determined by a degree 2 homogeneous polynomial in n+1 variables. How many coefficients are there?

Comment: Is it $\tfrac{1}{2}(n^2 + 3n)$ many? That is, can we say that $\tfrac{1}{2}(n^2 + 3n)$ many points will uniquely determine a hyperellipsiod in $R^n$ space?

Comment: not really. First, he formula for the number of coefficients is $(n+1)(n+2)/2$. Then you should subtract 1 because rescaling all the parameters makes no difference, but this is the number of *complex* points you need to specify a quadric. Also, some of these choices will give you paraboloids, hyperboloids, etc. So, I don't really know the answer to the question, I just thought that this perspective might be interesting!